# Qt: lupdate is converting Apostrophe in to &apos;

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, qt5, translation

I am running `lupdate` on my *Qt HMI application*. And I have noticed that few strings which has single quotes (for example `l'unite`) are replaced with its character entity **`&apos;`** (for example `l&apos;unite`) in the .ts files that are generated as result of `lupdate`.

Though this conversion has no adverse affects on the localization. I wanted to know why is that this behavior occurs. Is there a way to disable it ?

Any help on this is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the XML language definition. Since `'` is a special character in xml, it has to be escaped. Otherwise, a XML parser will not be able to read the file. In other words `&apos;` is nothing but an escape sequence for `'` and any XML reader will replace `&apos;` with `'` while reading the xml file.

The escape sequences are:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Comment: I usually perform an `lupdate` on my project file and share `.ts` files with our local translators. Usually they check for `<translation type="unfinished">` and give me a translated form of corresponding string and send back the `.ts` file to me. And, when I open that translated file I notice that these special characters (for ex: `&quot;`) that I sent in my original file are replaced with actual characters (ex: `"`). Why is that there is no escape sequence character in the xml file i received from our translators. Will it depends on the XML parser or editor tool  ?

Comment: It seems so. You should try to find out what kind of tool they use. If they use QtLinguist, that should not happen. If they use other tools, you may need to "convert" the TS files first to make shure those tools don't corrput them. (For example to a `.po`-file. This can be done using `lconvert <file>.ts -o <file>.po`).